# Sorting ItemsControl items based on a property defined declaratively in DataTemplate XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, itemscontrol

I'm looking for a simple way to sort items of ItemsControl based on a property specified in implicit DataTemplate for the items to which the control is bound. And defining the properties on DataTemplate is crucial here, because I cannot add the sorting property on the item itself.

So, for the below example VM layer:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FirstModel : INamed
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SecondModel : INamed
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Models = new INamed[] { new SecondModel {Name = "Second"}, new FirstModel {Name = "First"}};
    }

    public IEnumerable<INamed> Models { get; private set; }
}
```

and this attached property:

```
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    public static int GetSortOrder(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(SortOrderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSortOrder(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SortOrderProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SortOrderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SortOrder", typeof(int), typeof(AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

I have the following DataTemplate definitions (over-simplified):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstModel}">
    <StackPanel Background="Red" local:AttachedProperties.SortOrder="1">
        <Label>First's Name:</Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondModel}">
    <StackPanel Background="Green" local:AttachedProperties.SortOrder="2">
        <Label>Second's Name:</Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Somewhere the usage will be like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And here the order of the items should be based on the attached property I defined for the data templates. Don't see any option to use the CollectionViewSource directly here, may be I'm wrong...

Current options I see, none too appealing, are:

- Attached behavior on the ItemsControl, traversing the visual tree of each new item and sorting the Items in accordance with the found SortOrder value
- A custom ItemsControl with it's own sorting logic, panel, blackjack and... you know
- Wrapping the model instances in some kind of proxy with SortOrder property on it. Which still requires some custom/user control code-behind or ViewModel class changes

Is there some better/easier way I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant
I think the only way is to implement your own ItemsControl
Or wrap the models with another class

Maybe this helps:
[SortDescription with custom attached property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053559/sortdescription-with-custom-attached-property)

Comment: Yep, that was my guess also. Looked for an easier way though.